# Animate image from style not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, styles

I want to place the same animation to all my images in my application when someone hovers the mouse over them. As a result I have created the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="test" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">

        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" 
                    Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and on the image that I plan on animating I will apply that style as:

```
  <Image Style="{StaticResource test}" Name="image1" Source="/PDV;component/images/t.png" Stretch="Uniform" Width="100" />
```

when I hover my mouse over that image I get the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   Message=Cannot
>   animate '(0)' on an immutable object instance.
>   Source=PresentationFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.VerifyPathIsAnimatable(PropertyPath
>   path)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock
>   currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope,
>   DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath
>   parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary
>   clockMappings, Int64 layer)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock
>   currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope,
>   DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath
>   parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary
>
> etc..

What do I have to change to the style to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the storyboard Target. It will work fine then.

```
<Style x:Key="test" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" 
                **Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"**>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="200">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```